# Why does this Ember 2 store.createRecord('foo', {user: .., account: ..}) result in null user?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In this toy Ember 2 app, a **user** `models/user.js` and an **account** `models/account.js` have identical contents:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

The final **foo** `models/foo.js` belongs-to a user and to an account:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  user: DS.belongsTo({}),
  account: DS.belongsTo({}),
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

The `router.js` exposes creation of **foo** belonging to an **account**  and a **user**:

```
this.route('accounts', function () {
  this.route('one', {path: '/:account_id'}, function () {
    this.route('foos', function () {
      this.route('new');
    });
  });
});
```

The account id will come from the route, however the user id will come from somewhere else.

So, a route `accounts/one.js` exposes the **account** model:

```
model(params) {
  return this.store.findRecord('account', params.account_id);
},
```

A route `accounts/one/foos/new.js` exposes the create-a-new **foo** model. It will attempt to find the corresponding **user** record for the id it knows:

```
model() {
  let userId = 2; // it comes from "somewhere else"
  return this.store.createRecord('foo', {
    user: this.store.findRecord('user', userId),
    account: this.modelFor('accounts.one')
  });
},
```

The final resulting model has the correct `account` but null `user`.

What's the right way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

This version of `accounts/one/foos/new.js` works:

```
model() {
  let foo = this.store.createRecord('foo', {
    account: this.modelFor('accounts.one')
  });

  let userId = 2; // it comes from "somewhere else"
  this.store.findRecord('user', userId).then((record)=>{
    foo.set('user',record);
  });

  return foo;
},
```

Defining `foo` before returning it allows the promise of `user` to set its target when it resolves, *after* the closure of the original `model()` function call.